# Mapping column from one pandas DataFrame to another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'players.name': ['John', 'Will' ,'John', 'Jim', 'Tim', 'John', 'Will', 'Tim'],
                     'players.diff': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                            'count': [3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2]})
```

'count' values are constant.

---

And I have a different shape dataframe with players ordered differently, like so:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'players.name': ['Will', 'John' ,'Jim'],
                     'players.diff': [0, 0, 0]})
```

---

How do I map from `df_1` values and populate a 'count' value on `df_2`, ending up with:

```
  players.name  players.diff  counts
0         Will             0       2
1         John             0       3
2          Jim             0       1
```

Comment: Does your data frame have the same name in multiple rows, and if there are, are the values (count,diff) for those columns unique for each row available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just trying to create a column of counts, it'd be more meaningful to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) your player names to counts:

```
df_2['counts'] = df_2['players.name'].map(
    df_1.groupby('players.name')['count'].first())

df_2 

  players.name  players.diff  counts
0         Will             0       2
1         John             0       3
2          Jim             0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample `df_1` has duplicated `players.name` with same count, so you need left-merge and drop_duplicates

```
new_df_2 = df_2.merge(df_1[['players.name','count']], on='players.name', how='left').drop_duplicates()

Out[89]:
  players.name  players.diff  count
0         Will             0      2
2         John             0      3
5          Jim             0      1
```

Comment: It's `df_1` that has duplicated values.

Comment: @siamaksafari: it is typo :)

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=["players.name", "players.diff"]).drop_duplicates()
```